# Jmeter JDBC PreProcessor that returns values into variables

Tags: jmeter

Within the Jmeter there is a jdbc preprocessor which executes a script to insert preliminary setup data. The script includes auto generated Ids which are needed as assertions and to be subsequently used in the request body of the HTTP Request.
How do I get the values returned and set to user variables?

[image]

```
DECLARE @Q1 uniqueidentifier;  
SET @Q1 = NEWID() ;
....
 select @Q1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the resulting value as `${Q1_1}`. See [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler documentation on how to work with the results from the database.

In general using [NEWID](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function from Transact-SQL is an overkill, if you use it for just generating [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-like values - you can just use JMeter's [UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function for the same just where you need to use that generated ID structure. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.